# How to use a trigger to update when INSERTED but not using INSERTED value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to edit this command:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TG_DATA_U] 
ON [dbo].[TABLE2]
FOR UPDATE
AS
    UPDATE TABLE1 
    SET PRICE = (SELECT PRICE FROM INSERTED)
    WHERE ID = (SELECT ID FROM INSERTED)
```

Result needed:

TABLE 1

```
ID    PRICE
------------
 1     20
 2     11
```

TABLE 2

```
IDTABLE2   ID    PRICE    IDGROUP
---------------------------------
    1      1      20        1
    2      2      11        1
    3      2      15        2
```

I need to get the trigger to update the price in `TABLE 1` always and only with `IDGROUP = 1`, if I update the price "15" will only update `TABLE 1` with price "11".

Comment: Your trigger is fatally flawed; it *assumes* an `UPDATE` only effects one row at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this is what you want:

```
UPDATE TABLE1
    SET PRICE = (SELECT PRICE FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID = 11)
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM INSERTED);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Your trigger is flawed](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/): it assumes that `inserted` contains exactly one row. It may contain zero or multiple.

Your trigger should look like this

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TG_DATA_U] ON [dbo].[TABLE2]
FOR UPDATE
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE TABLE1
SET PRICE = i.PRICE
FROM TABLE1 t1
JOIN inserted i ON i.ID = t1.ID
WHERE t1.IDGROUP = 1
```

Answer (score -3):

Found a way much more simple, only using

"if (SELECT ID FROM INSERTED) = 1"

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TG_DATA_U] 

ON [dbo].[TABLE2]
FOR UPDATE
AS
if (SELECT IDTABELA FROM INSERTED) = 1
    UPDATE TABLE1 
    SET PRICE = (SELECT PRICE FROM INSERTED)
    WHERE ID = (SELECT ID FROM INSERTED)
```

Comment: Which will create an execution error when the inserted table contains more than 1 row. As already suggested, you have a common but fatal flaw in your code. Fix it now.